# Understanding default bibliography sort order

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bibliographystyle

I am trying to understand the somewhat surprising behavior I encounter with the Latex bibliography and bibitems with two+ authors. Here is a simple demonstrative `.bib` file:

```latex
@article{s0,
  title={Title},
  author={Aaronson, Aaron},
  journal={Journal},
  year={Year},
}

@article{s1,
  title={Title},
  author={Aaronson, Aaron and Christopher, Christina},
  journal={Journal},
  year={Year},
}

@article{s2,
  title={Title},
  author={Aaronson, Aaron and Baker, Brian and Dudley, Diedre},
  journal={Journal},
  year={Year}
}
```

Here is a minimal document that produces the bibliography:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Based on the listed authors, I would expect an alphabetized references list to make the following reference order:

1. Aaron Aaronson
2. Aaron Aaronson, Brian Baker, and Diedre Dudley
3. Aaron Aaronson and Christina Christopher

In fact, when I build this document, I get the following:

[image]

What is going on here? Is there a way to enforce the alphabetical ordering that I expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `plainnat` BibTeX generates the following sort names for the entries from the MWE

```
aaronson  aaron                                           % s0
aaronson  aaron   christopher  christina                  % s1
aaronson  aaron   zzYear   baker  brian   dudley  diedre  % s2
```

The last might be a bit surprising, but explains what is going on.

`plainnat` essentially makes sure that "Name et al." sorts under "Name zz" after all other "Name"/"Name and OtherName" combinations. Remember that with author-year citations, you only see "Aaronson et al." in the citations and not "Aaronson, Baker and Dudley". So it makes sense to sort the "et al." entries uniformly so that they can always be found easily and no additional knowledge about co-authors (which your readers won't have if they only know the citation label) is required.

Of course this sort order might be a bit weird for those who know the co-authors or for people who only read the bibliography.

If you want to force a different sorting order, you need to modify the `.bst` file directly.

1. Locate `plainnat.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `plainnat-allsort.bst`, say (the LPPL strongly encourages renaming changed copies of the original file)
4. Find `FUNCTION {sort.format.names}` (ll. 1207-1235) and replace the complete function definition with

   ```
    FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
    { 's :=
      #1 'nameptr :=
      ""
      s num.names$ 'numnames :=
      numnames 'namesleft :=
        { namesleft #0 > }
        {
          s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
          nameptr #1 >
            {
              "   "  *
              namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
                { "zzzzz" * }
                { t sortify * }
              if$
            }
            { t sortify * }
          if$
          nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
          namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
        }
      while$
    }
   ```
5. Add a comment with your name, the current date and a short description of the changes to the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-allsort}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` in your document.

As alternative for steps 1 to 5 you can obtain the patched version of the file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/6b7f057d814d8fbd3e3883bceeae91cd

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-allsort}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{s0,
  title   = {Title},
  author  = {Aaronson, Aaron},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {Year},
}
@article{s1,
  title   = {Title},
  author  = {Aaronson, Aaron and Christopher, Christina},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {Year},
}
@article{s2,
  title   = {Title},
  author  = {Aaronson, Aaron and Baker, Brian and Dudley, Diedre},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {Year}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{s0,s1,s2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aaron Aaronson. Title. Journal, Year.//Aaron Aaronson, Brian Baker, and Diedre Dudley. Title. Journal, Year.//Aaron Aaronson and Christina Christopher. Title. Journal, Year.]

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you!